# PyAutoGui - Detect pixelcolor

Tags: colors, rgb, detection, pyautogui

Good Evening,

I want to create a script that makes a screenshot of a certain region on my screen. It's a website with a lot of movement, where I want to test it.
If a pixel in the screenshot is white (255, 255, 255) it should do something, but first of all break the loop. If it isn't white, it should make another screenshot, until the pixel changes to a white color.

That's the script I made:

```
import pyautogui
from PIL import Image
import time

current = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(949, 502, 10, 5))
current.save("./current.png")

def rgb_of_pixel(img_path, x, y):
im = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))
a = (r, g, b)
return a


img = "./current.png"
print(rgb_of_pixel(img, 1, 1))
a = rgb_of_pixel(img, 1, 1)

while True:

if a == (255, 255, 255):
    print('It is white!')
    break

else:

    print(rgb_of_pixel(img, 1, 1))
    last = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(949, 502, 10, 5))
    last.save("./current.png")

    time.sleep(0.5)
```

It works if the pixel is already white when I start the script. But it doesn't work if the pixel changes in between the run. The console prints out the latest color, but it doesn't break the loop. What am I doing wrong?